# Pandas performance test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, performance-testing

I was trying to test for performance of different ways to select slices of a pandas dataframe. According to many sources online `pd.eval()` and `df.query()` should be much faster that the usual selection. Yet in my example below it is quite the opposite, with the "usual" method being invariably the fastest, over many different trials with different number of rows, or even with multiple expressions. Why do you think this is the case? I do have `numexpr` installed.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import time

random.seed(15)
n = 1000000

A = random.choices(range(1000),k=n)
df= pd.DataFrame(A, columns= ["A"])

a = time.time()
r1 = df[df.A>500]
b = time.time()
c = time.time()
r2 = pd.eval('df[df.A>500]')
d = time.time()
e = time.time()
r3 = df.query('A>500')
f = time.time()
print(np.allclose(r1, r2, r3))
print(b-a)
print(d-c)
print(f-e)
```

Output

```
True
0.02598261833190918
0.1059408187866211
0.031980276107788086
```

Comment: I'd be really surprised that `pd.eval()` is faster than usual selection considering all the overhead for translation from strings to actual python commands. Also I'm not sure about `query` but I bet it'd go for the exact same reason.

Comment: On my machine, if I execute this multiple times, the first execution is much slower than others (all others have almost the same timings). Here are results if the first run: 0.025, 0.051, 0.010. Here are results of all other runs: 0.0073, 0.0101, 0.0085. The difference is not so big... Thus maybe this claims come from the fact that it depends on the machine (and maybe other factors).